# AngularFire2 Getting Observable of type specific object

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I'm working on my first project using Angular and Firebase. Even thou everything works, I have a question about getting specific types of object. For example, I have a service that has a method called `getAllNews()`, but I want this return to be a type News (created by me, there is a NewsModel file) but when I set the type, I get this from TSLint:
`[ts]
Type 'Observable<{}[]>' is not assignable to type 'EventModel[]'.
Property 'length' is missing in type 'Observable<{}[]>`

Can anybody shine a light here for me? Thank you so much!

Here is my code:

**newsService.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { News } from '../news/news.model';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NewsService {

  NODE = 'news/';
  news: AngularFireList<News[]>;

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }

  getAllNews() {
    const localNews = this.db.list(this.NODE);
    return localNews.valueChanges();
  }

  getNews(id: string) {
    return this.db.object(this.NODE + id);
  }
}
```

**news.model.ts**

```
export class News {
    id: string;
    title: string;
    subtitle: string;
    article: string;
    picture: string;
}
```

**news.component.ts**

```
import { News } from './news.model';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NewsService } from '../services/news.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { NavController } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-news',
  templateUrl: './news.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./news.page.scss'],
})
export class NewsPage implements OnInit {

  news: any;

  constructor(private newsService: NewsService, private router: Router, private navController: NavController) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.news = this.newsService.getAllNews();
  }

  go(id: string) {
    this.navController.navigateForward('news/' + id);
  }
}
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly type what is coming back from the `AngularFireDatabase`. You're trying to assign an Observable to `EventModel[]`. Observables aren't arrays, but they can emit arrays. Implicit typing for the `Observable` is `{}`.

What I don't understand is where the `EventModel[]` typing is coming from. It's almost like `news: any` on news.component.ts was originally `news: EventModel[]` and Intellisense is being laggy. Either way, try:

```
  getAllNews() {
    const localNews = this.db.list<News>(this.NODE); // now should return Observable<News[]>
    return localNews.valueChanges();
  }
```

in news.component:

```
  news: Observable<News[]>;

  constructor(private newsService: NewsService, private router: Router, private navController: NavController) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.news = this.newsService.getAllNews();
  }
```

Comment: Hey @joh05667 thank you. Would that also be true for an object? Also if I get that object and I have a model linked to my class, I should be able to call any method on my model right? For example, `getFirstName()`.

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what you're asking. Type assertion and type safety are compile-time benefits in Typescript, but have no result on the compiled code. Giving the returned object a strong type will allow you to write more extensible code. However, you can give a return type of `object` or `any` and it would be just like working in vanilla JS, with no type safety.

Comment: Hey John, thank you! Sorry to be such a pain but I'm still having issues.
On my class I got this ref:
`currentUser: Observable<UserProfile>;`
Which is an observable of type UserProfile. UserProfile is a model:
`uid: string;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    email: string;
`
On my main comp I have a method that observes the user & I would like to type it as a **UserProfile** `this.currentUser = this.db.object('profile/' + user.uid).valueChanges();` I get: "Type Obervable<{}> is not assignable to type Observable<UserProfile>. Type {} is missing the following properties...